# How to get a pandas dataframe from an apache log?

Tags: python, pandas, apache

I'm trying to parse some apache log, but I'm having trouble making a dataframe from an apache log.

The log has this format:

```
201.179.162.179 - - [17/Sep/2019:06:30:49 -0300] "teSubmit=Save" 400 0 "-" "-"
201.179.162.179 - - [17/Sep/2019:06:30:49 -0300] "POST /cgi-bin/ViewLog.asp HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "-" "Ankit"
80.95.44.9 - - [17/Sep/2019:06:31:55 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12101 "http://netlab.ice.ufjf.br/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)"
50.31.26.18 - - [17/Sep/2019:06:32:14 -0300] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1514 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
50.31.26.18 - - [17/Sep/2019:06:32:14 -0300] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1897 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
file = open('access.txt')
lines = file.readlines()

logs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ip', 'indentd', 'userid', 'time', 'request', 'status', 'size', 'Referer', 'User_agent'])

regc = re.compile('(?P<ip>.*?) - - \[(?P<time>.*?)\] "(?P<request>.*?)" (?P<status>\d+) (?P<size>\d+) (?P<Referer>.*?) (?P<User_agent>.*?)')

for line in lines:
    m = regc.match(line)
    print(m)
    ip = m.group('ip')
    identd = m.group('identd')
    userid = m.group('userid')
    time = m.group('time')
    request = m.group('request')
    status = m.group('status')
    size = m.group('size')
    Referer = m.group('Referer')
    User_agent = m.group('User_agent')
    logs.append([ip, identd, userid, time, request, status, size, Referer, User_agent])

logs
```

And all I get as output is the column names. Does this `logs.append()` work the way I want?

Comment: but how you call the file log??.. I can´t see

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question code, try now.

Comment: try adding ignore_index=True like this =>   logs.append([ip, identd, userid, time, request, status, size, Referer, User_agent] , ignore_index=True )

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: can you give me a few lines example of your log apache?

Comment: sure, there it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok , I have this example , notice that I comment some lines :

```
import pandas as pd
import re

file = open('log.txt')
lines = file.readlines()

#logs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ip', 'time', 'request', 'status', 'size', 'Referer', 'User_agent'])
logs = pd.DataFrame({'ip': [], 'time': [], 'request': [], 'status': [], 'size': [], 'Referer': [], 'User_agent': [] })

regc = re.compile('(?P<ip>.*?) - - \[(?P<time>.*?)\] "(?P<request>.*?)" (?P<status>\d+) (?P<size>\d+) (?P<Referer>.*?) (?P<User_agent>.*?)')

for line in lines:
    m = regc.match(line)
    print(m)
    ip = m.group('ip')
    #identd = m.group('identd')
    #userid = m.group('userid')
    time = m.group('time')
    request = m.group('request')
    status = m.group('status')
    size = m.group('size')
    Referer = m.group('Referer')
    User_agent = m.group('User_agent')
    #logs.append([ip,time, request, status, size, Referer, User_agent], ignore_index=False)
    logs = logs.append({'ip':ip, 'time': time, 'request': request, 'status':status, 'size': size, 'Referer': Referer, 'User_agent':User_agent }, ignore_index=True)
print(logs.head())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just had to add quotation marks to the two last columns in the re.compile to catch what I want correctly but this was really helpful. Can I ask you just one more question?

Comment: is about this??..sure

Comment: Yes, I was trying another way... and if i have a list of rows of this log but in the list its in csv format, there would be an easy way to make a dataframe of it or I would have to do almost the same thing that I did with re to get each column?

Comment: But what I have is a list not a file, I got this list with re.match.groups() (it returns the line grouped as I want separeted by comma)

Comment: Sorry I was sleeping...but what exactly is your Goal?..what do you want with this log??